# How do you vertically align text to the middle of an image?

Tags: html, css

Please look at the following jsFiddle and alter appropriately. I basically want the text to be perfectly in the middle of the images height.

http://jsfiddle.net/e7AV9/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set it as a background image and center it there and then add a bit of left padding like this http://jsfiddle.net/e7AV9/5/

Comment: That still doesn't look centred, the text needs to be higher.

Comment: You can also add px position to it as well if you want more control of the positioning http://jsfiddle.net/e7AV9/13/

Answer (score 1):

I'm partial to absolute positioning.

*CSS*

```
* {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 10px;
}

nav > ul li:nth-child(2) a:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 9px;
    left: -2px;
    content: url(http://s2.postimage.org/1waex5o10/9j41t1.png) " ";
}

nav a {
    color: #626262;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
}
```

*HTML*

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="forum.php">Community</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

​

Answer (score 1):

You could also put the image directly in the HTML and style it that way: http://jsfiddle.net/e7AV9/10/

Here's the problem with [CSS:content](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/content.html):

> I feel that we shouldn't use the content declaration at all. It adds
>   content to the page, and CSS is meant for adding presentation to the
>   page, and not content. Therefore I feel that you should use JavaScript
>   if you want to dynamically generate content. CSS is the wrong tool for
>   this job.

Comment: Completely agree with that statement.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution can be just to add vertical-align: top such as this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Vh6wP/.

Also here's a link on vertical-align: http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/ for other values.